# Partitioning done incorrectly?

Tags: ubuntu, partition, system-installation

Long story short, we had issues installing linux on this system. It magically decided to work, but now I'm unsure about the hard drive partitioning.

One hard drive has linux installed on it and the other is just for storage at the moment. It shows 2 partitions of 256GB each on a single drive when the hard drive is only 256GB in size. Is it confused somehow? Did we break it?

[image: GUI version]

Output from fdisk -l

```
Disk /dev/sda: 256.1 GB, 256060514304 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 31130 cylinders, total 500118192 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000eef50

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      499711      248832   83  Linux
/dev/sda2          501758   500117503   249807873    5  Extended
/dev/sda5          501760   500117503   249807872   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/sdb: 256.1 GB, 256060514304 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 31130 cylinders, total 500118192 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00067612

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1              63   500118191   250059064+  83  Linux

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: 238.7 GB, 238723006464 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 29023 cylinders, total 466255872 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1: 17.1 GB, 17070817280 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 2075 cylinders, total 33341440 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1 doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of terminal output. They make the page heavier and slower to load and, in this case, are hard to read. Just copy/paste the text directly into yout question, using the [formatting tools](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to make it look like code.

Comment: Fixed output terminal image. There's 2 physical disks, one is just storage. It's the main disk (selected in image) I was confused about.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`/dev/sda2` is an **extended partition**.
`/dev/sda5` is an **logical partition** which is placed inside the extended partition.

Originally there could be only 4 partitions on a hard disk. To circumvent this, the extended partition was invented and further partitions, so called logical partitions, could be created inside the extended partition.

The partitions 1-4 are always primary partitions or the extended partition. Partitions 5+ are logical partitions inside the extended partition.

So everything is all right with your disk /dev/sda even if there are two 256 GB partitions - because one of them is inside the other.

P.S.
 What I said is true for drives with an MBR partition table. AFAIK drives with GPT partitions don't have those limitations.